# How does one populate an NSMutable array of NSMutableSets?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using this code in a loop to populate an NSMutable Array of NSMutableSets (of NSString objects). The index of the NSSet is based on the length of the word.

```
    // if set of this length not initialized yet, initialize set.
    wordIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentWordLength];
    if ([myWordArray objectForKey:wordIndex] == nil)
        [myWordArray setObject:[[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:currentWord, nil] forKey:wordIndex];
    else
        [[myWordArray objectForKey:wordIndex] addObject:currentWord];
```

The final intention is to split up an array of words into an array of sets of words grouped by their lengths.

However, I see that `[myWordArray count]` is 0 after this. Why?

Comment: You call your variable myWordArray but you're treating it like a dictionary?  Also, are you initializing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the methods of NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray: In Objective-C arrays do not have keys but have indexes. If you change the class for `myWordArray` to NSMutableDicitionary it should work.

Comment: Thank you. In that case, what is the right way to retrieve an element from an NSMutableArray?

Comment: `- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index`. However that will throw an exception if `index >= [array count]`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it looks very much like your logic, but (1) it uses NSNumbers as keys, which makes a little more sense, (2) handles the missing set condition more simply, but just adding the set,  and (3) breaks up the source lines somewhat for easier debugging...

```
NSArray *inputStrings = // however these are initialized goes here
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *currentString in inputStrings) {
    NSInteger currentWordLength = currentString.length;
    wordIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentWordLength];
    NSMutableSet *wordSet = [result objectForKey:wordIndex];
    if (!wordSet) {
        wordSet = [NSMutableSet set];
        [result setObject:wordSet forKey:wordIndex];
    }
    [wordSet addObject:currentWord];
}
```

If you still have an empty dictionary after running this, it might be simpler to watch what's happening by stepping through it.